# Critical inductance for buck converter

Tags: power, buck, converter

I have this problem: -

> [image]

The critical current must be \$P_{out} = V_{out}I_{crit} \Rightarrow I_{crit}=\dfrac{45\text{W}}{16\text{V}} = 2.8125 \text{A} \$

Using eq. 3.43 from Ned Mohan's book we have

$$I_{crit} = \frac{V_{in}}{2Lf_{sw}}\cdot D(1-D) $$

Solving for \$L\$, using that for a buck \$D=\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$ and inserting values gives us

$$L = \frac{V_{in}}{2I_{crit}f_{sw}}\cdot D(1-D) = \frac{42\text{V}}{2\cdot2.8125\text{A} \cdot 160\text{kHz}} \cdot \frac{16\text{V}}{42\text{V}}\Bigg(1-\frac{16\text{V}}{42\text{V}} \Bigg) =11.005\text{uH}$$

I have some questions. First, is my calculation correct? Second, what does this **critical**  inductance tell us about the circuit? Would we ever want to use this inductor value in our buck converter?

**EDIT**

Attempting to replicate aconcernedcitizen's LT-Spice simulation yields good results, but they are not quite identical: -

[image]

Comment: Your calculations look good to me.  And critical inductance is L_min for CCM so, you can use a large inductance.

Comment: I doubt anyone will get angry if you [checked for yourself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF9qg.png).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Okay, I will from now on. One last thing, though. I have tried to recreate your simulation myself in LT-Spice and it gave similar results, but not quite. Your simulation of I(L1) seems to have a sharper "snap" at 0A such that the buck actually operates in BCM. However, with the exact same values my I(L1) seems to spend a noteworthy time at 0A, thus operating in DCM instead of BCM. Did you use some special settings that are not shown in the picture you have linked?

Comment: @Carl No, but you did, two things: `vfwd` is `10u`, not `1m` (but it looks like it goes unnoticed), and you have added `vrev=1k`, which I didn't. This last one seems to influence the behaviour, and I'd venture a guess it's because of the rather large dynamic range (`10u` and `1k`). Possible solutions: remove `vrev`, remove `revepsilon` (or both), make `revepsilon=1m`, make `vrev=0.1k`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Unfortunately, those things didn't change the result. I believe some of my settings in "Hacks" may be different. Anywho, I think the result from the simulation is enough evidence that \$L_{crit} = 11.01\text{uH}\$ despite there being a little interval of I(L1) = 0A.

Comment: @Carl Try this: delete your `.model` lines and replace them with these (you'll need to use `Ctrl+Enter` appropriately): `.model diode d ron=1m roff=10meg vfwd=1m vrev=100 epsilon=1m revepsilon=1.model switch sw ron=1m roff=10meg vt=0.5 vh=-0.5` (that's `vh=-500m`, not `50m`, and `vfwd=1m` is more than enough, no need to tempt the numerical devil). The `level=2` was a whim at the time, and it also cheats you in the initial transient (becaue `Ilimit` defaults to `10`, and I haven't touched that setting).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Doing all that still leaves me with the same result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJi5X.png    I don't think there is anything more you can do. I really appreciate all the help you have given me.

Comment: @Carl I have no idea why the difference. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CudIG.png) is what I currently have. There are no parasitics set, the settings in the *Control Panel > SPICE* are untouched, using `.opt method=gear` doesn't change the response, or the alternate solver. OTOH, I see you have a custom symbol for the resistor, is it a resistor underneath, or something else (some use it to hide an inductor, to make it a quasi-real resistor, with parasitics)?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Using the default resistor returns same results. As a last resort, here is my LT-Spice settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Vv1.png  Perhaps something is different there? If not, then this will just be a mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the extended discussion, yes, the calculations are correct (also noted by [@G36, in the comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/611812/critical-inductance-for-buck-converter?noredirect=1#comment1612287_611812)), and the verification confirms it:

[image: confirmation]

---

As for why your results differ, even after the [last comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/611812/critical-inductance-for-buck-converter?noredirect=1#comment1613109_611812), my settings only differ by having checked *Supply a min. inductor damping if no Rpar is given* and *Enable beta circuit matrix optimizations* in the *Control Panel > Hacks!* tab -- they're not the cause.

However, if I add `Rser=0.5` to the inductor, the result I get is suspiciously similar to yours:

[image: the culprit]

When I said to check whether you have parasitics defined, or not, you probably relied on <kbd>RClick</kbd>, only, which brings up the default component editor. And here is the catch: relying on the default dialog means that LTspice will add the relevant parasitics, all in one line, on the `SpiceLine`, in the "advanced" component attribute editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RClick</kbd>, seen in the picture above). But if you add any of the parasitics elsewhere, for example in the `Value2`, as seen above, bringing up the default component attribute editor will **not** show anything, but the value **is there**.

What's more, manually adding `Rser=1k`, for example, will make it appear in the `SpiceLine`, where it is added normally. And, because the 4 lines `Value`, `Value2`, `SpiceLine`, and `SpiceLine2`, are nothing but graphical helpers (minor exceptions apply), anything written in those lines will be concatenated and the netlist will show everything in one line. Thus, anything on the `SpiceLine` will appear after enything on the `Value2` line, and so it will take precedence (`1k` will be considered, not `0.5`).

So, with these in mind, the lesson to learn is to <strike>not waste people's time by</strike> verify<strike>ing</strike> hidden attributes with the "advanced" component attribute editor, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RClick</kbd>. BTW, you should have also checked the overall current shape, it should have warned you that there are hidden settings about.

Comment: Thank you for the thought, but you shouldn't have used the bounty. Reading it now, the conclusion sounds a bit harsh, and that was not my intention -- using `<strike>` was meant as a tongue-in-cheek. (also, it's spelled LTspice, but there are so many variants floating about, that it's probably a case of "to each his own")